# Unpack tuple in a string literal?

Tags: python

Here is a code:

```
a = 'a b c'
b = 'd'

def func(a):
    a_list = a.split(' ')
    return a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2]


print '1 = %s, 2 = %s, 3 = %s, 4 = %s' % (func(a), b)

(func(a), b)
```

gives an error.

I tried

```
(*(func(a)), b)
```

with no luck.

Comment: The last one should work.

Comment: This is python-2.x?

Comment: Yes, python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate tuples before passing them into string interpolation, use:

```
print '1 = %s, 2 = %s, 3 = %s, 4 = %s' % (func(a) + (b,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if your input is:

```
a = 'a b c'
b = 'd'
```

Then you can simply do:

```
c = a.split(' ')+[b]
print ', '.join(['{} = {}'.format(n+1,c[n]) for n in range(len(c))])
```